# NestJS/TypeORM Joining Many to Many With Custom Properties

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have a many-to-many relationship with custom fields exactly how the following link describes.

https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-many-relations#many-to-many-relations-with-custom-properties

Is it possible to add the @ManyToMany() decorator in addition to the @OneToMany? This would make querying shipments easier so I could join `product` directly to `shipments` without having to join through through the join column for certain queries. for example currently, If I want to select products that have been shipped between two dates, I cannot easily do that. I'd like to have `product.shipments` available to me directly.

Here are my Entities:

Shipment.ts

```
@OneToMany(
  () => ShipmentProduct,
  (shipmentProduct) => shipmentProduct.shipment, { cascade: ['insert'], eager: true },)

shipmentProducts: ShipmentProduct[];
```

Product.ts

```
@OneToMany(
  () => ShipmentProduct, (shipmentProduct) => shipmentProduct.product)

shipmentProducts: ShipmentProduct[];
```

ShipmentProduct.ts

```
@ManyToOne(() => Shipment, (shipment) => shipment.shipmentProducts, { onDelete:'CASCADE' })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'shipment_id' })
shipment: Shipment;

@ManyToOne(() => Product, (product) => product.shipmentProducts, {})
@JoinColumn({ name: 'product_id' })
product: Product;
```